# Parse characters in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL column with name txt_Full_Path which has data as given below

```
E:/My_Users//kpa1/eOReport - VSD.mrk 
E:/My_Users//krishr9/Report.mrk 
E:/My_Users//kristc/AllPAS.mrk 
E:/My_Users//kukerm/v1.mrk      
E:/My_Users//ksnedike/abcdef.mrk
```

how do I get the value after first occurrence of '//' moving from left to right?

so that I get these values in a new column.

```
kpa1
krishr9
kristc
kukerm
ksnedike
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(y VARCHAR(64))

INSERT @x SELECT 'E:/My_Users//kpa1/eOReport - VSD.mrk' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'E:/My_Users//krishr9/Report.mrk' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'E:/My_Users//kristc/AllPAS.mrk' 
UNION ALL SELECT 'E:/My_Users//kukerm/v1.mrk'
UNION ALL SELECT 'E:/My_Users//ksnedike/abcdef.mrk';

SELECT y, part = SUBSTRING(y, 2, CHARINDEX('/', y, 2)-2)
FROM (SELECT y = SUBSTRING(y, CHARINDEX('//', y) + 1, 64) FROM @x) AS z;
```

Results:

```
y                         part
------------------------  ----------
/kpa1/eOReport - VSD.mrk  kpa1
/krishr9/Report.mrk       krishr9
/kristc/AllPAS.mrk        kristc
/kukerm/v1.mrk            kukerm
/ksnedike/abcdef.mrk      ksnedike
```

You may also run into a case where there is no trailing subsequent `/` character, e.g. `'E:/foo//bar'` - if so then:

```
SELECT y, part = SUBSTRING(y, 2, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', y, 2),0),66)-2)
FROM (SELECT y = SUBSTRING(y, CHARINDEX('//', y) + 1, 64) FROM @x) AS z;
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, Ty for your post. It did work. I have 2000+ values in my column called txt_Full_Path. Writing UNION ALL SELECT would be tedious. Is there a simpler way to query my column w/o using table variable? TIA.

Comment: @Nemo, that was just to set up sample data to demonstrate the output given the values you listed in the question. You would of course take this query and replace `@x` with your actual table name and `y` with the actual column name.

Answer (score 2):

It's ugly, but it works:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YourValue, CHARINDEX('//', YourValue) + 2, 
    ABS(CHARINDEX('/', YourValue, CHARINDEX('//', YourValue) + 2) - 
        (CHARINDEX('//', YourValue) + 2)))    
FROM YourTable
```

**EDIT**

Added the `ABS()` function in the last portion to handle folders without a `/` after the `//`.

Comment: While admittedly there was no indication of "bad" data, this doesn't gracefully handle the case where the second instance of `/` might be missing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- agreed, but since it looks like this is trying to extract user folders, I assumed (danger!) the format would be consistent.  I don't believe your script handles a missing `/` either, however. Try: `'E:/My_Users//krishr9'`.  I get an `Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function.` error.

Comment: yes, did you see the second script in my answer, and the descriptive text that introduced it?

Comment: @Aaron -- embarassingly, no, I did not :|